# Using variable in re.match in python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to create an array of things to match in a description line. So I can ignore them later on in my script. Below is a sample script that I have been working on, on the side.

Basically I am trying to take a bunch of strings and match it against a bunch of other strings.

AKA:
 asdf or asfs or wrtw in string = true continue with script
 if not print this.

```
import re

ignorelist = ['^test', '(.*)set']

def guess(a):
     for ignore in ignorelist:
             if re.match(ignore, a):
                     return('LOSE!')
             else:
                     return('WIN!')

a = raw_input('Take a guess: ')
print guess(a)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bit of logic/flow problem.

You test the first term in the list. If it doesn't match, you go to the `else` and return `"WIN!"` without testing any of the other terms in the list.

(Also, `ignorelist` is outside the function.)

*[EDIT: I see you edited the question to include regular expressions, so I will edit the answer back to a `re` context...]* Note that you should use `re.search` instead of `re.match` if you want to give it actual regex since `re.match` only matches at the beginning of the line.

There are innumerable ways to change this, depending on how you want your program to work.

I would re-write `guess` along these lines. (You can also put `ignorelist` inside the function instead of passing it.):

```
ignorelist = [r'^test', r'[abc]set']

def guess(a,il):
    for reg in il:
        if re.search(reg,a):
            return "LOSE"
    return "WIN"

a = raw_input()
print guess(a,ignorelist)
```

In this case, it will loop through each word, exiting if it finds a match, but if it doesn't (completes the loop without returning anything) then it will finally return `"WIN"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be far better using a single regex, or a set of them if only one would be to big to compile. Something like:

```
GUESSER = re.compile('|'.join(ignorelist))

def guess(a):
    if GUESSER.search(a):
        return('WIN!')
    else:
        return('LOSE!')
```

Note: Pattern in "ignorelist" should be enclosed in a pair of parentheses if they use the or "|" operator.